# If for every point in the interval there is a neighborhood in which $f$ is increasing then is $f$ throughout increasing?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Let $f$ be a real valued function defined on an open interval $(a,b)$ such that for each interior point $x\in(a,b)$ there is an $\epsilon>0$ neighborhood of $x$ in which $f$ is increasing ; then how to show that $f$ is increasing throughout  in $(a,b)$  ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a substantial suggestion, rather than a full proof, because the question asks how to prove

Suppose it were true $f(x)\gt f(y)$ for some $x\lt y$ and $x,y\in (a,b)$.

Now consider the function $f$ on the compact interval $[x,y]$ and derive the contradiction that $f(x)$ must be $\le f(y)$.

Comment: Sorry , but the thing is I have tried in vain to find a contradiction !!!

Comment: @SouvikDey. You can use compactness to stitch - crucially - a finite number of pieces of $f$ together on open subintervals $[x,y]$ in such a way that you can bridge the interval with points such that $f(x)\le f(x_1) \le \dots \le f(x_n)\le f(y)$. You find the points $x_r$ where the open subintervals overlap, so each jump is contained within an open set where you know that $f$ is increasing.